# Read Data From Excel Which Is Updating Simultaneously in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my first post. I want to read excel file in python 3 which is updating every second. this is what i have tried

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import xlrd
>>> parsed=pd.read_excel(open("PATH TO FILE","rb"),sheet_name="Default")
>>> parsed
```

i always get same old data. 
[Old Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Npq8x.png)

But not updated data, 
[Updated Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbb8o.png)

even if i call last statement again. Please help

I tried to open excel with read_excel after update of excel file but still getting old results.

I tried few things more and found that i was not able to get right result because excel was updated by server but not saved after each return. When i forcefully saved excel during updates. I got updated results. But how can i save automatically excel with each update?

Comment: This asnwer might be useful as it also deals with a similar topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419888/reading-from-a-frequently-updated-file

Comment: Well your last statment is printing same data that you have fetched before in your 2nd last statement call your 2nd last statement after updating data then call the last statment

Comment: @raghav710 how to open excel file like that? aren't we supposed to use pandas for this or xlrd module

Comment: @AbdullahAhmedGhaznavi i tried 3rd statement for opening file in freash way but again i got same results

Comment: @YugKaswan waiting for the file to change and then reading in the fresh data should be a good approach. As suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47709010/read-and-plot-real-time-live-self-updating-csv-file

Comment: You'll have to close and open the file each time you want to get updated results.

Comment: @raghav710 file doesn't save automatically until i explicitly save it.

Comment: @YugKaswan can you please clarify that point. Isn't the data written by some program into the excel file and automatically saved?

Comment: @raghav710 data is written by a server but not saved automatically in excel.... is there any way in python to save excel file written by server

Comment: @YugKaswan where does the server write the data? is it some file?

Comment: @raghav710 server writes data in a excel file every second but doesn't save it, to save file i have to explicitly save it.

Comment: Excel is being updated every second?  I find that hard to believe.  Whatever data source is being fed into Excel, should probably be fed directly into Python, if that's your end game.